# How can I remove duplication between methods that differ only on type but use non-default constructors?

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, methods

Hello I got many methods (below 2 examples) that look almost exactly the same. The difference is in **name of JSON breanch** that is processed, **type of returned list** and **type of objects added to list**. I know these example methods yet needs some optimization in its body, but the case is to pass type of returned value and type of class which method currently need and make it all work. If it is possible I would like to avoid casting in place of calling method.

**Method 1**

```
    public static List<Box> JsonToListOfBoxes(string data)
    {
        List<Box> ListOfBoxes = new List<Box>();
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
        {
            JObject productsJson = JObject.Parse(data);
            JToken jtkProduct;

            jtkProduct = productsJson["boxes"];

            if(jtkProduct != null)
                if(jtkProduct.HasValues)
                {
                    int childrenCount = productsJson["boxes"].Count();
                    for(int x = 0;x < childrenCount;x++)
                        ListOfBoxes.Add(new Box(productsJson["boxes"][x]));
                }
        }

        return ListOfBoxes;
    }
```

**Method 2**

```
    public static List<Envelope> JsonToListOfEnvelopes(string data)
    {
        List<Envelope> ListOfEnvelopes = new List<Envelope>();
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
        {
            JObject productsJson = JObject.Parse(data);
            JToken jtkProduct;

            jtkProduct = productsJson["envelopes"];

            if(jtkProduct != null)
                if(jtkProduct.HasValues)
                {
                    int childrenCount = productsJson["envelopes"].Count();
                    for(int x = 0;x < childrenCount;x++)
                        ListOfEnvelopes.Add(new Envelope(productsJson["envelopes"][x]));
                }
        }

        return ListOfEnvelopes;
    }
```

Comment: @LuisLavieri that one is obvious for me, i got stuck with class type and returned type

Comment: I did not see the Box and Envelope objects. You have to go with Generics for sure

Comment: I think you're getting some workable solutions, but I think from an API standpoint, you might be well served by keeping the public surface as you already have it, and then extract the redundant pieces into a private helper method. This allows you to limit the `T` to types you know you are equipped to handle and make business sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make generic method where `dataName` should be "boxes" or "envelopes":

```
public static List<T> JsonToListOfBoxes<T>(string data, string dataName)
{
    List<T> ListOfItems = new List<T>();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
    {
        JObject productsJson = JObject.Parse(data);
        JToken jtkProduct;

        jtkProduct = productsJson[dataName];

        if (jtkProduct != null)
            if (jtkProduct.HasValues)
            {
                int childrenCount = productsJson[dataName].Count();
                for (int x = 0; x < childrenCount; x++)
                    ListOfItems.Add((T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), productsJson[dataName][x]));
            }
    }

    return ListOfItems;
}
```

*Use example:*

```
var list1 = JsonToListOfBoxes<Box>("dataString", "boxes");
var list2 = JsonToListOfBoxes<Envelope>("dataString", "envelopes");
```

Comment: `new T(productsJson[dataName][x])` won't compile, you can't use constructor parameters with generics.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain How about this?

Comment: Using `Activator.CreateInstanc` still feels like code smell to me so it won't earn you a +1 but I will get rid of the -1 since the code does do its job.

Comment: Also Activator.CreateInstance should not be used in a tight loop, as it is incredibly slow. It would make more sense to pass in a lambda.

Comment: @Aron It was just a suggestion I had on my mind at the moment, no need to hate ;)

Answer (score 5):

Using generics you can change as follows : (without parameterized generic constructor)

```
    public static List<T> JsonToListOfEnvelopes<T>(string data, string searchString, Func<string, T> creator)
    {
        List<T> ListOfEnvelopes = new List<T>();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
        {
            JObject productsJson = JObject.Parse(data);
            JToken jtkProduct;

            jtkProduct = productsJson[searchString];

            if (jtkProduct != null)
                if (jtkProduct.HasValues)
                {
                    int childrenCount = productsJson[searchString].Count();
                    for (int x = 0; x < childrenCount; x++)
                        ListOfEnvelopes.Add(creator(productsJson[searchString][x]));
                }
        }

        return ListOfEnvelopes;
    }
```

And you can call it as

```
        var result = JsonToListOfEnvelopes("data", "boxes", c => { return new Box(c); });
        var result = JsonToListOfEnvelopes("data", "envelopes", c => { return new Envelope(c); });
```

Answer (score 0):

I just changed @msmolcic logic a bit.

```
public static List<T> JsonToListOfBoxes<T>(string data)
{
    List<T> ListOfItems = new List<T>();
    string dataName = typeof(T) == typeof(Box) ? "boxes" : "envelopes";

      //if there are many types one can try in below way..
      // if (typeof(T) == typeof(Box))
      //  {
      //      dataName = "Box";
      //  }
      //  else if (typeof(T) == typeof(Envelope))
      //  {
      //      dataName = "envelopes";
      //  }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
    {
        JObject productsJson = JObject.Parse(data);
        JToken jtkProduct;

        jtkProduct = productsJson[dataName];

        if (jtkProduct != null)
            if (jtkProduct.HasValues)
            {
                int childrenCount = productsJson[dataName].Count();
                for (int x = 0; x < childrenCount; x++)
                    ListOfItems.Add((T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), productsJson[dataName][x]));
            }
    }

    return ListOfItems;
}
```

Comment: The question references *many methods* but he gives 2 as an example. Your solution bakes in just the 2 variations shown and would not handle the others.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram I just added commented code snippet. Just have a look. This solution helps if user don't want to pass additional parameters and limited types.